# I do not understand this paragraph explaining web browser caching

Tags: http, caching

I was reading through some HTTP documentation and found this paragraph to be very confusing:

> "The more we use cached resources, the better the responsiveness and the performance of a Web site will be. To optimize this, good practices recommend to set expiration times as far in the future as possible. This is possible on resources that are regularly updated, or often, but is problematic for resources that are rarely and infrequently updated."

Why is it problematic for resources that are rarely updated? Isn't it the opposite? If the resource is updated rarely, then once you save a specific cache, you are good for a long time (maybe 5 years). But if the resource is updated everyday, then you have to download the 'fresh' cache every single day WHICH is problematic. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem when it is rarely updated, but if you do not know in advance when.

Comment: but isn't it more of a problem if it is frequently updated and you do not know in advance when?